# Dynamically change title of Today Widget?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios9, today-extension, ios9-today-widget

Is it possible to dynamically change the title of the Today Widget? I'd like to add the users current location next to the app name of the widget title, so it will change constantly per user for all users. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

No it's not possible.
They are came from CFBundleDisplayName at info.plist and localized strings that are singing target.

It means that they are static resources and it can't be changed after signing.